# One command to create a directory and file inside it linux command

Tags: linux, command-line

Suppose my current directory is **A**. I want to create a directory **B** and a file "myfile.txt" inside **B**.

How to do that in one command from Terminal?

**Edit:**

Directory can be nested multiple times. Like I may want to create **B/C/D** and then "myfile.txt" inside that. I do not also want to repeat the directory part.

Following command will create directory at any level.

```
mkdir -p B/C/D
```

and

```
mkdir -p B/C/D && touch B/C/D/myfile.txt
```

will create the directory and the file. But I do not want to repeat the directory part after the `touch` command. Is that possible?

Comment: Write a shell script.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
mkdir B && touch B/myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, create a function:

```
mkfile() { mkdir -p -- "$1" && touch -- "$1"/"$2" }
```

Execute it with 2 arguments: path to create and filename.  Saying:

```
mkfile B/C/D myfile.txt
```

would create the file `myfile.txt` in the directory `B/C/D`.

Comment: This, however does not support TAB completion unlike a "real" command like `mkdir` does.

Answer (score 9):

For this purpose, you can create your own function. For example:

```
$ echo 'mkfile() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1" ;  }' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ mkfile ./fldr1/fldr2/file.txt
```

Explanation:

- Insert the function to the end of `~/.bashrc` file using the `echo` command
- The `-p` flag is for creating the nested folders, such as `fldr2`
- Update the `~/.bashrc` file with the `source` command
- Use the `mkfile` function to create the file

Comment: is there any package available in linux that can give the same functionality [in the form of a command] as this `makefile` command?

Answer (score 5):

```
mkdir -p Python/Beginner/CH01 && touch $_/hello_world.py
```

Explanation:

`-p` -> create parent and child directories

`$_` -> use it for current directory we work with inline

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple command below is enough.

```
mkdir a && touch !$/file.txt
```

Thx

Comment: This would work in bash but not in zsh or fish.  Not sure about other shells.  Also mkdir -p a/b/ might be better.  Lastly "" would be better to handle things like spaces

Answer (score 3):

You could create a function that parses argument with `sed`;

```
atouch() {
  mkdir -p $(sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/' <<< $1) && touch $1
}
```

and then, execute it with one argument:

```
atouch B/C/D/myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

1-to make your own command add this to ~/.bashrc:

```
function mkfile() { 
    mkdir -p  "$1" && touch  "$1"/"$2" 
}
```

save and then to make it available without a reboot or logout execute: `$ source ~/.bashrc`
then you can use it: `mkfile myfolder myfile.txt`

2-or without new command you can just type:

```
$ mkdir folder && touch $_/file.txt
```

note that $_ = folder here

Answer (score 0):

devnull's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17986639/9933916) provides a function:

```
mkfile() { mkdir -p -- "$1" && touch -- "$1"/"$2" }
```

This function did not work for me as is (I'm running bash 4.3.48 on WSL Ubuntu), but did work once I removed the double dashes. So, this worked for me:

```
echo 'mkfile() { mkdir -p "$1" && touch "$1"/"$2" }' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
mkfile sample/dir test.file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install the script ;

```
pip3 install --user advance-touch
```

After installed, you can use ad command

```
ad airport/plane/captain.txt
```

```
airport/
├── plane/
│   ├── captain.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Below commands I tried on **Windows 10 machine with  git-bash**. *And that worked for me*.
Let's say I want to create a directory named **"Files"** and under this directory I want to have "file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt" ..etc files

```
mkdir Files && touch $_/file1.txt $_/file2.txt $_/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in installing a 3rd party App

Bonk is written in rust and is a greatly improved version of rust

https://github.com/elliot40404/bonk

to install from crates.io

```
cargo install bonky
```

Create nested file inside nested directories

```
bonk src/bonky/mod.rs
```

I normally prefer vanilla solutions, but bonk adds so many features I feel it is superior to creating functions and other work arounds. It looks like a new program and the code appears safe to me.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the show but, here is how I typically approach this in bash:

```
mkdir -p "$(dirname "/path/to/file.extension")" && touch "/path/to/file.extension"
```

`dirname` will grab the folder structure and create it for you. The `touch` command will create your actual file.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir B && sudo vim B/myfile.txt
```

you can leave your file.txt empty.

Answer (score -5):

This might work:

```
mkdir {{FOLDER NAME}}
cd {{FOLDER NAME}}
touch {{FOLDER NAME}}/file.txt
```

Comment: It will not because of the change directory command. Remove that, and it will work.