# Create file along with nested directory in single command line

Tags: linux, file, nested, directory, mkdir

I want to create a file `abc.php` within a directory `a/b/c` which does not exist yet. I need to do it with a single command like this `mkfile a/b/c/abc.php` I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986615/one-command-to-create-a-directory-and-file-inside-it-linux-commad) solution which suggests solution like this `mkfile a/b/c abc.php`.

**And along with this I would love to have the file opened in an editor which happens with nano command.**

Usually while following tutorials we have to create file and copying and pasting their file directory without editing makes life simpler.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: Why not a short script that takes the path and filename as an argument and then `[ "$1" != "${1##*/}" ] && mkdir -p "${1%/}"; touch "$1"; exec nano "$1"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you simply want to be able to issue `command foo/bar/baz/myfile.txt` (or something similar) and have the directories `foo/bar/baz` created and a new file `myfile.txt` created and opened in `nano` all by that one command, then a short script is all you need, e.g.

Make it **executable** e.g. `mv nanoopen.sh scriptname; chmod 0755 scriptname`, then just call `./scriptname` `foo/bar/baz/file.txt`. If you put it in your path, **you can skip the ./ too**.

The easy way to put it in your path is to create a symlink to it in `/usr/local/bin` which is generally in the default path. 
So you could (sometime supersure is needed) **`ln -s /path/to/nanoopen.sh /usr/local/bin/scriptname`**. **Echo $PATH** to confirm **/usr/local/bin** is in your path, then just use it like any program, scriptname arguments.
Or in some distros you can simply add it to `/bin` folder with root access.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate one argument given
    printf "error: insufficient input\nusage: %s filename\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1    
}

[ "$1" != "${1##*/}" ] && mkdir -p "${1%/*}"  ## if it has directories, create
touch "$1"                                    ## create the file

exec nano "$1"     ## open in nano
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash nanoopen.sh foo/bar/baz/main.c

$ tree foo/
foo/
└── bar
    └── baz
        └── main.c

$ cat foo/bar/baz/main.c
My new source!
```

Comment: I tried this it is exactly what I want. Cannot we do without having to use bash and .sh before and after command.?

Comment: Sure, just call the script anything you like and make it executable (e.g. `mv nanoopen.sh scriptname; chmod 0755 scriptname`) then just call `./scriptname foo/bar/baz/file.txt`. (if you put it in your `path`, you can skip the `./` too) The easy way to put it in your path is to create a symlink to it in `/usr/local/bin` (which is generally in the default path). So you could (sometime `supersure` is needed) `ln -s /path/to/nanoopen.sh /usr/local/bin/scriptname`. (`echo $PATH` to confirm `/usr/local/bin` is in your path), then just use it like any program, `scriptname arguments`.

Comment: I have added this in my /bin folder

Comment: Yes, that works too for distros like SuSE that provide `~/bin` within the default path. (just note that not all distros do) Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Thank you for this.