# Explode a single file script into a project with proper directory layout

Tags: bash

**The problem**

Suppose that I have written a lengthy script
in some language "lang",
and now want to convert this single-file script
into a directory tree with a project consisting of many files. I want to insert some kind of separators and file-paths into this file, and process it in some way so that in the end I obtain:

- a proper project directory layout [(sth. like this)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html),
- build-definition file,
- readme's,
- separate subdirectories for `main/src` and `test/src` etc.

For example, given the following script (pseudocode):

```
// required dependencies, should be moved
// into the build definition build.foo
require "org.foo" % "foo-core" % "1.2.3"
require "org.bar" % "bar-gui" % "3.2.1"

// A longer comment that should be converted
// into a text file and moved into a 'notes'
// subdirectory

/*
#README

Another lengthy comment that should go into
a readme.md
*/

/** A class that should 
  * go to src/main/lang/proj/A.lang
  */
class A {
  def a = "foo"
}

/** Another class
  * that should go to src/main/lang/proj/B.lang
  */
class B {
  def b = "bar"
}

/** Some tests,
  * should end up in 
  * src/test/lang/proj/MyTest.lang
@Test def testFoo() {
  assert(2 + 2 == 5)
}
```

and assuming that I can insert arbitrary separators, commands, escape-sequences and file paths into this file, I would like to obtain the following project:

```
project/
|-- build.txt
|-- notes
|   `-- note_01.txt
|-- readme.md
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- lang
    |       `-- proj
    |           |-- A.lang
    |           `-- B.lang
    `-- test
        `-- lang
            `-- proj
                `-- MySpec.lang
```

---

**Edit:**

What follows is a less-sophisticated version of my [own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040399/2707792)

---

**What I've tried**

Here is one naive way to do it:

- Convert the original script into a bash script by prepending `#!/bin/bash`
- split the source code into HEREDOCS
- insert package declarations where necessary
- add bunch of `mkdir -p` and `cd` between the HEREDOC-pieces
- `cat` the HEREDOC pieces into appropriately named files
- test the script on empty directories until it works as expected

For the above script, it might look somehow like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir project
cd project

cat <<'EOF' > build.txt
// required dependencies, should be moved
// into the build definition build.foo
require "org.foo" % "foo-core" % "1.2.3"
require "org.bar" % "bar-gui" % "3.2.1"
EOF

mkdir notes
cd notes
cat <<'EOF' > note_01.txt
// A longer comment that should be converted
// into a text file and moved into a 'notes'
// subdirectory
EOF
cd ..

cat <<'EOF' > readme.md
/*
#README

Another lengthy comment that should go into
a readme.md
*/
EOF

mkdir -p src/main/lang/proj
cd src/main/lang/proj
cat <<'EOF' > A.lang
package proj

/** A class
  * that should go to src/main/lang/proj/A.lang
  */
class A {
  def a = "foo"
}
EOF

cat <<'EOF' > B.lang
package proj
/** Another class
  * that should go to src/main/lang/proj/B.lang
  */
class B {
  def b = "bar"
}
EOF
cd ../../..

mkdir -p test/lang/proj
cd test/lang/proj
cat <<'EOF' > MySpec.lang
package proj

/** Some tests,
  * should end up in 
  * src/test/lang/proj/MyTest.lang
@Test def testFoo() {
  // this should end up in test
  assert(2 + 2 == 5)
}
EOF
cd ../../..
```

**What's wrong with this approach**

It does generate the correct tree, but this approach seems rather error-prone:

- it's too easy to `cd ../../..` to the wrong nesting level
- too easy to `mkdir` with a wrong name, and then fail to `cd` into it.
- There is no way to handle the entire tree construction as a single
  transaction, that is, if something fails later in the script,
  there is no simple way to clean up the mess generated before
  the error occurred.

I certainly could try to make it a bit less brittle by defining
special functions that `mkdir` and `cd` in one go, and 
then wrap invocations of those functions together with `cat`s into
`(mkdirAndCd d ; cat)` etc.

But it just doesn't feel quite right. Isn't there a much simpler 
way to do it? Could one somehow combine the standard bash/linux utilities
into a tiny & very restricted domain specific language for
generating directory trees with text files? Maybe some newer version of `split` where one could specify where to split and where to put the pieces?

---

**Related questions:**

- [`mkdir` and `touch` in single command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17986639/2707792)
- [The reverse of `tree` - reconstruct file and directory structure from text file contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140730/the-reverse-of-tree-reconstruct-file-and-directory-structure-from-text-file)

---

**Other interesting proposals** that don't seem to work:

- Use tar. That would mean that one would have to convert the text file manually into a valid tar-archive. While a tar archive indeed *is* a single plain-text file, its [internal format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#UStar_format) does not look like the most comfortable DSL for such a simple task. It was never intended to be used by humans directly in that way.
- Similar argument holds for `shar`. Since `shar` uses the bash itself to extract the archive, my above proposal is, in principle, a manually generated shar-archive in a very uncommon format, therefore `shar` seems to share all the drawbacks with the above proposal. I'd rather prefer something more restricted, that allows to do fewer things, but provides more guarantees about the quality of the outcome.

Maybe I should emphasize again that I don't have a tree to begin with, so there is nothing to compress. I have only the single script file and a rough idea of what the tree should look like in the end.

Comment: Why not a `tar` file? Or, if it has to be a shell script, a [sharchive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar)?

Comment: You mean manually converting a raw text file into a tar and then untar it? I somehow didn't think about it... Must look up what the internal format of `tar` looks like before I can say whether this proposal is genius or crazy or both :) Never heard of `shar`, reading about it right now.

Comment: A `tar` file *is* the raw text file you are looking for (assuming all the archive members are themselves text files). (So would the `shar` file, even more so.) Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @melpomene I've looked at `shar`. It seems useful only for the direction 'directory tree -> file'. If I don't have a tree to begin with, what I wrote down in my proposal already seems to be the simplest "shar" that generates the tree. Shar is a way to compress existing trees, not a comfortable DSL for describing new directory trees. So, that's not quite what I hoped for. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @chepner It might be that I just don't use it correctly, but the internal format of (uncompressed) tar didn't look like the most comfortable way to define new directory trees in a text file. Maybe I didn't express it clearly enough: the question is not about creating an archive from an existing tree, it's about a human-readable format for *defining* new trees with text files from scratch. I've updated my question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I don't see why you don't just create the individual files, then package them with `tar`, `shar`, or the archiver of your choice. Why invent a new format that you write directly?

Comment: @chepner Because I have experimentally found out that creating all those files in neat package-trees is annoying. The evidence is: I have dozens of bloated "sketches" with several thousand lines of code laying around, because I often simply start scripting, and then keep writing, but in the end never convert it to a proper project. Now it happened *again*, I'm sitting on a way-too-long script that needs a proper structure to be tested, but I'm just too lazy to copy-paste all the snippets into right places, because I'm sure I'll want to move them around and try various package layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(my own answer)

---

Consider the following definition of a tiny embedded domain specific language for defining directory trees with text files:

```
#!/bin/bash

enter() {
  local subdir="$1"
  if [ ! -d "$subdir" ]
  then
    mkdir -p "$subdir"
  fi
  pushd "$subdir" > /dev/null
}

leave() {
  popd > /dev/null
}

save() {
  local fileName="$1"
  cut -d'|' -f2- > "$fileName"
}
```

The `enter` command creates a directory if necessary, and `cd`s into this directory, it works with arbitrary relative paths. The `save` command saves the text content of a here-document to file. The `leave` command changes to previous directory.

When a file is saved, the margin (empty space followed by '|') is stripped from each line. This is to ensure that the indentation of the script does not interfere with the indentation of the written files.

If these definitions are `source`d, then the tree-generation script can be written as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

source explode.sh

mkdir project
cd project

enter "src"
  enter "main/lang/proj"
    save "A.lang" <<'____EOF'
      |package proj
      |
      |/** A totally useful class
      |  * that should go to src/main/lang/proj/A.lang
      |  */
      |class A {
      |  def a = "foo"
      |}
____EOF

    save "B.lang" <<'____EOF'
      |package proj
      |/** Another very useful class
      |  * that should go to src/main/lang/proj/B.lang
      |  */
      |class B {
      |  def b = "bar"
      |}
____EOF
  leave

  enter "test/lang/proj"
    save "MyTest.lang" <<'____EOF'
      |package proj
      |
      |/** A test that should end up in 
      |  * src/test/lang/proj/MyTest.lang
      |@Test def testFoo() {
      |  assert(2 + 2 == 5)
      |}
____EOF
  leave
leave

save "build.txt" <<'EOF'
  |require "org.foo" % "foo-core" % "1.2.3"
  |require "org.bar" % "bar-gui" % "3.2.1"
EOF

enter "notes"
  save "note_01.txt" <<'__EOF'
    |A longer comment that should be converted
    |into a text file and moved into a 'notes'
    |subdirectory. This is a very long comment
    |about the purpose of the project. Blah 
    |blah blah.
__EOF
leave

save "README.md" <<'EOF'
  |#README
  |
  |This is a readme file for my awesome project.
  |It ends with this line. Bye.
EOF
```

When executed, the script generates the following directory tree:

```
project/
├── build.txt
├── notes
│   └── note_01.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── lang
    │       └── proj
    │           ├── A.lang
    │           └── B.lang
    └── test
        └── lang
            └── proj
                └── MyTest.lang
```

The `bash`-script mirrors the tree structure very closely, and it's impossible to mess up the `cd ../../../../../..` commands. It still lacks various desirable properties though (not transactional, no dry-run capability).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are trying to write a custom parser. Provided that all blocks mentioned by you are ended by double line endings, this could help you

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n([/][*]|[/]{2,2})"} 
        { 
        if ($0 ~ /#README/){
                system("echo -e \"\nThis is a Readme.md\n--------\n" $0 "\"")
        }else if ($0 ~ /class /){
                system("echo -e \"\nThis is a class\n---------\n/*" $0 "\"")
        }else if ($0 ~ /require /){
                system("echo -e \"\nthis is a conf\n-----------\n" $0 "\"")
        }else if($0 ~ /[/]{2,2}.*\n[/]{2,2}/){
                system("echo -e \"\nthis is a note\n-----------\n" $0 "\"")
        }

}' your_script.lang
```

The key part is the record separator RS that splits block of code that start with '\n\n//' or '\n\n/*'.
Instead of `echo -e` you could write custom scripts for each type of block.
Please note that the record separator will not be present on $0 so you have to add the missing characters, as in the /class / example above.

The output of the above code is

```
this is a conf
-----------
// required dependencies, should be moved
// into the build definition build.foo
require org.foo % foo-core % 1.2.3
require org.bar % bar-gui % 3.2.1

this is a note
-----------
A longer comment that should be converted
// into a text file and moved into a 'notes'
// subdirectory

This is a Readme.md
--------

#README

Another lengthy comment that should go into
a readme.md
*/

This is a class
---------
/** A class that should 
* go to src/main/lang/proj/A.lang
*/
class A {
def a = foo
}

This is a class
---------
/** Another class
* that should go to src/main/lang/proj/B.lang
*/
class B {
def b = bar
}
```

About your concerns:

- it's too easy to cd ../../.. to the wrong nesting level
  -> define a variable with root path and cd to it.
- too easy to mkdir with a wrong name, and then fail to cd into it.
  -> define variables with directory names and check if they already exists.

  path1=src/main/lang/some
  if [ -d $path1 ]; then
      do_something
  fi
- There is no way to handle the entire tree construction as a single transaction ...
  -> write to file paths of every NEW directory/file that you create and use it to revert if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMuñoz for a reply. I hope that I can avoid writing any parsers for that. As you can see from my solution proposal, splitting the file into blocks isn't a problem at all, you can insert arbitrary separators whereever you want (I didn't care to insert `<<'EOF'` before and `EOF` after each block). The problem is that it's kind of difficult to guarantee that the resulting directory tree structure is well-formed. In your script, I don't really see any code that generates directories or files at all, so I'm not sure how it answers the question? What is supposed to create the tree?

Comment: I mentioned writing small scripts to replace `echo` commands in my example. you can create directories there. The good side of the script above is that you don't have to change the source scripts. With custom scripts for each type you don't have to go back and forth over diirectories. Each script will handle its own type.

Comment: It's not a problem to change the script, because it's trivial to make a copy of it. About the `echo`s: well, yes, I could replace the `echo`s by the `cat`-statements, as in my proposed solution. I just don't see any point in calling them from `awk` instead of calling them directly. As I said, "finding" the blocks and separating them isn't a problem at all, because you can simply insert whatever separators you want. Finding the input isn't the problem. Making sure that all the outputs end up in a coherent directory structure -- that is the problem.

Comment: how many different directories do you expect to have? You can create them in advance with `mkdir -p`. How many different languages and scripts do you need to parse? Perhaps it's easier to make that manually.

Comment: Current example: I have a 3k lines long sketch that I want to split into, say, 30 files, in maybe 5-6 packages/subpackages (twice, because of `src/main` and `src/test` subtrees). It's scala, and I have to split it because I want to make some tests that use reflection, but unfortunately, it stops working in script-mode, because of ... weird scala-reflection specific reasons. I don't want to `mkdir` in advance, because I might want to adjust the script later so that the files are inserted into directory tree of a larger existing project. Don't want to do it manually, sry :] But Thx anyway