# Make Nested Directories and Files with Linux

Tags: linux

I want to create parent, child, and grandchild folder using linux command. So the the parent folder will be MUSIC. In MUSIC folder I'll have two folders which are ROCK and CLASSIC. Then inside ROCK I want to have two txt files which are PUNK and GOTHIC, and inside CLASSICAL I want to have two txt files BAROQUE and EARLY. How to make these without "cd" command. I was thinking of using the "mv" command, but is there another better idea besides moving the files one by one? I put the diagram in the picture below. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTuOK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you are using `bash`, or some other shell that supports the `{}` notation:

```
mkdir -p music/{rock/{punk,goth},classical/{baroque,early}}
```

Use all caps if you want, but it seems excessive.

--EDIT--

In the above, I had mistakenly thought that `punk`, `goth`, etc. were to be created as directories.  If you want them to be files (with no content), you could do:

```
mkdir -p music/{rock,classical}
touch music/{rock/{punk,goth},classical/{baroque,early}}
```

It seems odd to bother with `touch`, though.  It would be better to delay creating the files until you actually provide content.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. But OP asked for the leaves to be regular files. Any better idea than to create a function `touch-p` that calls `mkdir -p` on the dirname of its args, then `touch` on the args themselves?

Comment: @raphinesse Ah, I did not notice that `punk`, `goth`, etc were regular files.  `touch` is probably not the right thing to do though, since I presume those files are actually going to have content.  I would say they should be created by whatever mechanism the OP is using to generate the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the full path from the root folder. Then you do not need to `cd` inside any dirs.

```
user@user-Inspiron:~$ mkdir root_music
user@user-Inspiron:~$ mkdir root_music/category1
user@user-Inspiron:~$ mkdir root_music/category2
user@user-Inspiron:~$ touch  root_music/category1/f1.txt
user@user-Inspiron:~$ touch  root_music/category1/f2.txt
user@user-Inspiron:~$ touch  root_music/category2/f1.txt
user@user-Inspiron:~$ touch  root_music/category2/f2.txt
```

which gives you:

```
user@user-Inspiron:~$ tree root_music/
root_music/
├── category1
│   ├── f1.txt
│   └── f2.txt
└── category2
    ├── f1.txt
    └── f2.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986615/one-command-to-create-a-directory-and-file-inside-it-linux-command) answer is more relevant to your question.

```
mkdir -p B && touch B/myfile.txt
```